# API WebExtensions, communicate between browser and content script

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to communicate from a web page to an extension and vice versa.

To do so, I looked at the Mozilla documentation here : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#Communicating_with_the_web_page

And it has a simple example, but I can't make it work. On the web page script, I have this :

```
// page-script.js

var messenger = document.getElementById("from-page-script");

messenger.addEventListener("click", messageContentScript);

function messageContentScript() {
  window.postMessage({
    direction: "from-page-script",
    message: "Message from the page"
  }, "*");
```

On the content scripts page in the extension :

```
// content-script.js

window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
  if (event.source == window &&
      event.data.direction &&
      event.data.direction == "from-page-script") {
    alert("Content script received message: \"" + event.data.message + "\"");
  }
});
```

I installed the extension (as a temporary one, I uploaded my xpi file), then I used the "Debugging" method of API WebExtensions, and put a breakpoint into the listener, but whenever I call the PostMessage, the extension never seems to receive the event, the breakpoint is never triggered.

Is it possible to communicate this way between a web page and an extension ? Or is there another one ?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Your code works in my environment. There are couple of things you can check: try to use unpacked extension instead of xpi, check that both scripts are loaded. Try to run `messageContentScript()` from the page console.

Comment: Thanks Anatoly Sazanov, I figured it out. As I was adapting my Chrome extension to a Firefox extension, I used a background script. And I didn't see it first but the manifest declared my content script as a background script, hence the error.

Comment: Voting to close as "non-reproducible / typo", as the issue is from an accidental error in the environment, not the code presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the manifest of my extension. I declared my content script as a background script.

So, instead of writing this :

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["myscript.js"],
    "persistent": true
    },
```

You have to declare the script like this :

```
   "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"]
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing similar issues and the problem for me is I was calling the

```
window.postMessage
```

function from within an iframe.  After I changed this to

```
top.window.postMessage
```

it started working.